# Parse string in python in dict

Tags: python, parsing

I have a string after sql query like this:
`"['user_id=c370,'good_cnt=2','good_id=1999','igoodid=12341','good_id=1111','good_id=1214','good_id=1437']"`
Can I parse it not manually in dict: `{'user_id': 'c370','good_cnt':2,'good_id': [1999, 12341, 1111, 1214, 1437]"`

Comment: We're happy to comment on your code but you have to share it.

Comment: 1. It's pretty bad that you need to deal with such a non-standard format to begin with; consider if you can change this in any way. 2. Is there a `'` missing after the first value…? 3. Parse the string into a list with `ast.literal_eval`, and then maybe join it with `&` into a query parameter string, and parse it with `urllib.parse.parse_qs`? That seems pretty close to what you want…

Comment: There is a `'` missing from the first `user_id`, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qs
>>> literal_eval(s)
['user_id=c370', 'good_cnt=2', 'good_id=1999', 'igoodid=12341', 'good_id=1111', 'good_id=1214', 'good_id=1437']
>>> '&'.join(literal_eval(s))
'user_id=c370&good_cnt=2&good_id=1999&igoodid=12341&good_id=1111&good_id=1214&good_id=1437'
>>> parse_qs('&'.join(literal_eval(s)))
{'user_id': ['c370'], 'good_cnt': ['2'], 'good_id': ['1999', '1111', '1214', '1437'], 'igoodid': ['12341']}
```

Unless you have specific reasons not to use this, this seems like the sanest option. If you really want some values as single values and others as lists, you could post-process this:

```
>>> {k: v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in parse_qs('&'.join(literal_eval(s))).items()}
{'user_id': 'c370', 'good_cnt': '2', 'good_id': ['1999', '1111', '1214', '1437'], 'igoodid': '12341'}
```

Or, to go for a complete different approach:

```
r = {}

for i in literal_eval(s):
    k, v = i.split('=')

    if k not in r:
        r[k] = v
    elif isinstance(r[k], list):
        r[k].append(v)
    else:
        r[k] = [r[k], v]
```

```
>>> r
{'user_id': 'c370', 'good_cnt': '2', 'good_id': ['1999', '1111', '1214', '1437'], 'igoodid': '12341'}
```